# SequenceInputStream basic test failing

Tags: java

Believe it or not, this test fails to pass on my end. It's my first time working with SequenceInputStream and I wanted to test its functionality. From this test, it seems like completeIs only gets to stream the contents from is2. For the tests to pass is2 & is1 need to be concatenated.

```
public void testCombineInputStreams() throws IOException {
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
List<InputStream> isList = new ArrayList();

String charSet = "UTF-8";

String str2 = "world!";
strBuffer.append(str2);
InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(str2.getBytes(charSet));
isList.add(is2);

String str1 = "hello";
strBuffer.append(str1);
InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(str1.getBytes(charSet));
isList.add(is1);

SequenceInputStream completeIs = new SequenceInputStream(new Vector(isList).elements());

String completeStr = strBuffer.toString();

int expectedNumBytesRead = completeStr.getBytes(charSet).length;
byte[] readStr = new byte[expectedNumBytesRead];

assertEquals(expectedNumBytesRead, completeIs.available());
completeIs.read(readStr, 0, expectedNumBytesRead);
assertEquals(completeStr, new String(readStr, charSet));
}
```

Is there anything I've missed here?

Comment: What `SequenceInputStream`? I see no `SequenceInputStream` in the code.

Comment: What is `completeIs`? What is point of `isList` when you never use it?

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for pointing out that detail (I've edited the code now). It's a copy paste error on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: your way of converting a `List` into an `Enumeration` is bad (it copies the whole list into a new array that will then be wrapped in a `Vector`.)

It would be better to use

```
SequenceInputStream completeIs = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(isList));
```

which wraps an `Iterator` in an `Enumeration`.

---

The problems:

1. you expect `completeIs.available()` to return the total amount of available bytes from all enclosed `InputStream`s.

   However, according to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#available()):

   > [returns] an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) **from the current underlying input stream** [..]
2. you expect `completeIs.read(readStr, 0, expectedNumBytesRead)` to read all bytes from all enclosed `InputStream`s.

   However, according to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

   > The read method of SequenceInputStream **tries to read the data from the current substream. If it fails to read any characters** (because the substream has reached the end of the stream, it calls the close method of the current substream and) **begins reading from the next substream**.

To fully read data from an `InputStream` (be it a `SequenceInputStream` or some other variant), you **always** need to read in a loop until the `read()` method returns `-1`

Comment: I edited the code in the question, I forgot to add that one line you mentioned

Comment: @MrBuggy ah, I see it now. I've updated my answer accordingly